# Send AJAX request to Django view with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm trying to send a `GET` AJAX request to a Django view using vanilla JS. `is_ajax()` passes but I could not retrieve the request object properly.

Here is my JS code. With/out `JSON.stringify(data)` doesn't work.

```
document.querySelector('#testForm').onsubmit = () => {
      let data = {category : 'music'};

      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', 'test/', true);
      request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

      request.onload = () => {
        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(data);
      }

      request.send(data);
      return false;
});
```

And here is my Django view:

```py
def test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print('Yes!')
        data = {'category': request.GET.get('category', None)}
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

It prints `Yes!` to the terminal but I get back a `{category: null}` in the console.

This JQuery code works and I get the expected `{category: "music"}` response:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'cart/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
```

I'm wondering what I'm missing in the vanilla JS code or in my Django view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET requests can't have a body, so the `data` parameter to `request.send` is ignored. You should make it part of the URL itself:

```
request.open('GET', 'test/?category=music', true);
```

Comment: Thanks! So JQuery does this under the hood? The thing is, I'll be passing a longer data object so I guess I'll just use JQuery for convenience.